# Issue connecting to SQL Server 2012 with JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm attempting to connect to a SQL Server 2012 DB with JDBC.  My connection code is:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");      
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://<server_name>:1433", "username", "password");
```

However `getConnection()` is throwing the following exception:

```
The server version is not supported. The target server must be SQL Server 2000 or later.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(Unknown Source)
```

I've downloaded the latest JDBC jar from Microsoft (I've actually tried about half a dozen different versions of the sqljdbc#.jar file).

What else could cause this problem?

Comment: *[Drivers for relational access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/sql-connection-libraries#anchor-20-drivers-relational-access)* Are you sure you get the newest one 6.2?

Comment: Yes, I've tried both 6.0 and 6.2.

Comment: I am able to connect using JTDS drivers.

Comment: Is it possible that you have more than one .jar file for mssql-jdbc on your Build Path (CLASSPATH)? I just searched the source code for the 6.x version of the mssql-jdbc driver and the exact error message you quoted does not appear, suggesting that you may actually be loading an older version of the driver.

Comment: Yes! There was an older version of sqljdbc.jar buried in a User Library that is in my classpath.  Once I moved the newer version up in the build order, the error went away.  (Please add as Answer so I can give you credit for solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying several different versions of a driver, e.g., for troubleshooting purposes, be careful not to leave multiple .jar files for (different versions of) the driver on your Build Path (CLASSPATH) because the resulting behaviour can be confusing.

Also, code like this might shed some light on the problem:

```java
try {
    java.sql.Driver d = (java.sql.Driver) Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
    System.out.printf("%d.%d", d.getMajorVersion(), d.getMinorVersion());
} catch (InstantiationException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you keep seeing the same value (e.g., `"6.1"`) then you may not really be loading a different version of the driver.